# Redux Observable Action with payload types don't match. But without payload its working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable

[image]

The code is as follows

```
import { Action } from "redux";
import { ActionsObservable, ofType, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

export enum ActionTypes {
    One = 'ACTION_ONE',
    Two = 'ACTION_TWO'
}

export interface One extends Action {
    type: ActionTypes.One
    //commnent out next line to remove error
    myStr: string
}

export const doOne = (myStr: string): One => ({ 
    type: ActionTypes.One,
    //comment out next line to remove error
    myStr 
})

export interface Two extends Action {
    type: ActionTypes.Two
    myBool: boolean
}

export const doTwo = (myBool: boolean): Two => ({ type: ActionTypes.Two, myBool })

export type Actions = One | Two

export const epic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Actions>) => 
    action$.pipe(
        ofType<Actions, One>(ActionTypes.One),
        map((action: any) => ({
            type: ActionTypes.Two,
            myBool: true
        }))
    )

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(epic)
```

Also how I generate the store

```
import { createEpicMiddleware } from "redux-observable"
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux"
import { reducer } from "./reducer"
import { rootEpic } from "./epic"

export const configStore = () => {

    const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware()

    const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware))

    epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)

    return store
}
```

I have spent last 4 hours trying to add payload to action but with every possible filter solution it fails. I tried asking for help on redux observable github section and their chat room. I also googled for simple example that is strictly typed. Didn't find any solution.

Comment: I was able to get it working by using (action$:any) instead of (action$: ActionsObservable<Actions>)  But its not perfect solution.

Comment: This is actually a really good question I would also like a better answer for.

Comment: I ended up typing rootEpic as never to represent that it accepts generic type (basically)

Comment: I dropped redux completely and now maintain global state with plain hooks. Infact I will soon drop react completely for hottest new framework sveltekit.

Comment: I just started a rebuild of my company's app using react and redux as it follows the same pattern as Angular. I don't know enough about svelt yet to confidently recommend it as a framework.

Comment: I would recommend to drop redux. And maintain global state with vanilla hooks and context api. Unless your app is like figma that is heavily interactive and has large amount local state then you need redux. Most app just don't. Sveltekit is relatively new.  Just keep an eye on it. Its going to get big very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just follow [typesafe-action github](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) example. This repository really care about being strictly typed. Redux observable people only care if it works with javascript. And if it doesn't work with strictly typed typescript then they simply ignore the problem. And ignore any request for help. Luckily typesafe-action example was built with redux observable so it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue than you, my solution was:

As you stricly typed your epic:

```
export const epic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Actions>)

// Not the subject, but I would prefer
export const epic: Epic<Actions> = action$ =>
```

You have to stricly type your epicMiddleware too:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware<Actions>()
```

With this, your `epicMiddleware.run` method will attempt `Actions` instead of `Action<any>` and it should work.

Comment: I get the following error on `export const epic: Epic<Actions> = action$ =>` line. Argument of type '(source: Observable<Actions>) => Observable<Actions>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Actions, PostAction>'.
  Type 'Observable<Actions>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PostAction>'.
    Type 'Actions' is not assignable to type 'PostAction'.
      Type 'ErrorAction' is not assignable to type 'PostAction'.
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type 'ActionTypes.ERROR' is not assignable to type 'ActionTypes.POSTS'.ts(2345)

Comment: Instead of fixing my code if you could just create very basic example of redux observable in typescript react with strictly typed then it would help me a lot.